# sed make partial of the patterns matching

Tags: bash, sed, grep

My task is: input six strings and a file name, pull out all the lines that meets at least three patterns out of the six.

e.g: `./test.sh p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 file.txt` so the line `aabbbp1p3p5p4` matches but `oop4op2ooo` not.

so what's the key point to write the command `sed` or `grep` in my shell in a few lines? (`awk` might also be tried, but i'm not familiar with it too much)

The last thing I want to do is to enlist permutation.

Comment: Not clear, please do add more detailed information about your sample of Input_file and expected output in your question and let us know. Most importantly please do add your efforts in your question which you have put in order to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to farm out to other tools.
All bash -

#### test.sh:

```
pats=("$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6") # get the patterns
file="$7"                            # assign the source
while read -r line                   # read each line
do declare -i hits=0                 # initialize hits
   for p in "${pats[@]}"             # loop through patterns
   do case "$line" in                # comparing to input
      *"$p"*) (( hits++ )) ;;        # increment on match
      esac                  
   done
   (( hits > 2 )) && echo "$line"    # print on threshhold
done < "$file"                       # reading from file
```

#### file.txt

```
p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6
p1 p2 p3 p4 p5
p1 p2 p3 p4
p1 p2 p3
p1 p2
p1
.
```

Executed:

```
$: ./test.sh p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 file.txt
p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6
p1 p2 p3 p4 p5
p1 p2 p3 p4
p1 p2 p3
```

Comment: For higher efficiency, use something other than `bash` - do the whole thing in `awk`, or `python`, or `perl`, etc.... but `bash` can totally handle it. The only real bottleneck is probably the `read`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. I changed the order of the parameters so the first parameter is the filename and all others are patterns :

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ "$#" -lt 4 ]] && { echo "You need at least 4 arguments. A filename and 3 patterns"; exit 3;}
filename="$1" && shift
patterns=( $@ )

[[ ! -f "$filename" ]] && { echo "File '$filename' does not exist"; exit 4;}

matches=0
while read line
do
    matches=0
    for p in "${patterns[@]}"
    do
        grep -q "$p" <( echo "$line" ) && (( matches++ ))
    done
    [[ "$matches" -ge 3 ]] && echo "$line";
done <<< "$( cat $filename )"

exit 0
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you want efficient solution that scale well. For scripting, this implies running as few external commands as possible (each external command like `grep` require lot of resources to launch).

The following solution will read the data files only 6 times (each is a single grep), count the number of matches for each line, and print only the lines with >=3 matches.

```
patterns=("$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6")
file=$7


for p in "${patterns[@]}" ; do grep -- "$p" "$file" ; done |
sort |
uniq -c |
awk '$1 >= 3 { print gensub("^ *[0-9]+ ", "", 1) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel '(({1}<{2})) && (({2}<{3})) && echo "/p{1}/{/p{2}/{/p{3}/b}}"' ::: {1..6} ::: {2..6} ::: {3..6} |
sed -f - -e 'd' filename.txt
```

This will filter out all lines from `filename.txt` which do not have 3 or more matches from the set `{p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6}`.